# Finding general formula for a recursively defined series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone please show me how to solve the following question please, I am very lost. Suppose that the sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2...$ is defined by $x_0 = 6$, $x_1 = 2$, and $x_{k+2} = −6x_{k+1}−8x_k$ for k≥0. Find a general formula for $x_k$.

Comment: Try listing out the first few terms i.e $x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5,...$. Do you notice a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to finding the general and particular solution to a differential equation $y''+ay'+b = 0$ using undetermined coefficients, but instead of our answers being in terms of $e^x$, they will be in terms of $a^x$.

To find the general solution of this recursion, we need a characteristic equation.  Let $u^k = x_k$ so the characteristic equation is $$u^2 + 6u + 8 = 0$$

This is an easy factorization, so we get $$(u+4)(u+2)=0 \Rightarrow u = -2, -4$$

Our general equation will look like $$x_k = A(-4)^k + B(-2)^k$$ but we need to find the coefficients A and B.

For $x_0=6$, $$A(-4)^0+B(-2)^0 = 6 \Rightarrow A+B = 6$$

For $x_1=2$, $$A(-4)^1+B(-2)^1 = 2 \Rightarrow -4A-2B = 2$$

Now we must find $A \text { and } B$, and we do so by solving the system of equations $$\begin {matrix} A + B = 6 \\ -4A - 2B = 2 \end {matrix}$$

and doing so we get $A = -7$ and $B = 13.$ Thus the general equation for $x_k$ is $$x_k = -7(-4)^k + 13 (-2)^k$$